# Converting UIImage to UIData in monotouch fails

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimage, xamarin, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

I've seen variations of my questions on stack overflow but haven't had any answers that have worked for me.  I'm trying to convert an image I retrieve via UIImagePickerController to an NSData object.  In the debugger after I call AsJPEG the NSData object has text that appears as...

```
System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString': the native 'initWithDa…
```

(note the debugger cuts off the string)

My code is fairly straight forward (taken form samples on stack overflow)

```
    protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia (object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e) {
        // determine what was selected, video or image
        bool isImage = false;
        switch(e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString()) {
        case "public.image":
            Console.WriteLine("Image selected");
            isImage = true;
            break;
        case "public.video":
            Console.WriteLine("Video selected");
            break;
        }

        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        path = Path.Combine (path, "media");
        if (!Directory.Exists (path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory (path);
        path = Path.Combine (path, Path.GetRandomFileName ());

        // get common info (shared between images and video)
        NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl;
        if (referenceURL != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Url:"+referenceURL.ToString ());

        // if it was an image, get the other image info
        if(isImage) {
            // get the original image
            UIImage originalImage = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;

            if(originalImage != null) {
                // do something with the image
                Console.WriteLine ("got the original image");

                using (NSData imageData = originalImage.AsJPEG(0.75f)) {
                    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, dataBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
                    File.WriteAllBytes (path, dataBytes);
                }
            }
        } else { // if it's a video
            // get video url
            NSUrl mediaURL = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaURL] as NSUrl;
            if(mediaURL != null) {
                // ...
            }
        }          

        // dismiss the picker
        NavigationController.DismissViewController (true, null);
    }
```

I've seen other posts that suggested it was the size of the UIImage, so I've experimented with cropping it.  Same result.  I've also tried AsPNG, same result.  I even tried scaling down the image to 1/4 it's original size and still get the error.

I think the key is the mention of NSString, which tells me something's fishy... as the native C call used in Xcode doesn't involve an NSString, so I think something else is going on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get a crash? Or is it just the debugger you're worried about?  Why are you using 'Marshal.Copy' instead of simply 'NSData.Save()': `imgData.Save(pngFilename, false, out error)` - that should perfectly save your image to disk as PNG. The issue with `NSString` probably is with the debugger only while it tries to show you a human readable representation of the `NSData` object.

Comment: So my question is that the NSData object is invalid.  Your suggestion seems to be an alternate method for saving once you have a valid NSData object.

Comment: You don't answer my question: why do you think your NSData is invalid? Is your app crashing and breaking while debugging? Or is the exception above from the output of the debugger when evaluating your NSData object? If you're debugging and it crashes and you cannot see the full exception, use the "Immediate" window and type `$exception` and paste the result here.

Comment: Fair enough.  So typing $exception in the immediate window I get 'Evaluation Failed'.  The reason I think there's an issue is that in the debugger the Value field shows the string 'System.Exception: Could not initialize an instance of the type 'MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString': the native 'initWithDa…'  for the NSData field.  The app doesn't crash when run in the debugger.

Comment: @BryantHarris The exception you are seeing in the debugger windows is an issue with the debugger. I assume it looks like this: http://screencast.com/t/6CE8xLaknrIC NSData does not contain a string, which is what the debugger is trying to convert it too. This should be fixed soon in a newer release. Also, this is similar: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17693. The question still remains though: What is the problem? The debugger window showing you that exception when inspecting imageData could be a red herring.

Comment: Also, this might help: http://weblogs.asp.net/chrishardy/archive/2009/11/03/converting-a-uiimage-to-a-bytearray-in-monotouch.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment from therealjohn, this appears to be an error with the debugger when it converts a value to a string to display it in the debugger window it seems to run into an error.  The NSData object is actually fine.